# Intellij 2017.2.1 issue with glassfish

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm having issues setting up glassfish in intellij. I've set it from run/debug configuration and it reads as glassfish 4.1.1, when i run a project with it i have `GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0` . But under JRE in the glassfish configuration page i have Default(9 - Project SDK) .

Comment: GlassFish 4.1.1 will not run on JDK 9

Comment: So there's not yet a version that supports jdk9 ?

Comment: No, JDK 9 hasn't yet been released. The most recent version of GlassFish (4.1.2) was released before the spec for JDK 9 was even finalised.

Comment: [You could try Payara Micro which can be run on JDK 9](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1814#issuecomment-318583638). Payara code is derived from GlassFish so could probably run your app. The easier way is to target Java 8 for now, though.

Comment: Thanks for the information